# Display manager doesn't load desktop and instead shows a black screen for 5 minutes after entering login info. then loads after the 5 minutes

Tags: gnome, login, password, gdm

After I get to the login screen from a reboot, once I enter my password and login, instead of getting the desktop, I get a completely black screen for exactly 5 minutes, once those 5 minutes have passed, the desktop loads without any error messages.

Version: 21.04

Kernel: 5.13.0-7620-generic

GNOME Shell 3.38.4

NVIDIA Driver Version: 470.82.00

`systemctl status gdm3.service` output:

```
systemd[1]: Starting GNOME Display Manager...
systemd[1]: Started GNOME Display Manager.
gdm-launch-environment][1352]: pam_unix(gdm-launch-environment:session): session opened for user gdm by (uid=0)
gdm-password][1912]: pam_unix(gdm-password:auth): Couldn't open /etc/securetty: No such file or directory
gdm-password][1912]: pam_unix(gdm-password:auth): Couldn't open /etc/securetty: No such file or directory
gdm-password][1912]: gkr-pam: unable to locate daemon control file
gdm-password][1912]: gkr-pam: stashed password to try later in open session
gdm-password][1912]: pam_unix(gdm-password:session): session opened for user pc by (uid=0)
gdm-password][1912]: gkr-pam: gnome-keyring-daemon started properly and unlocked keyring
gdm3[1309]: Gdm: Child process -1372 was already dead.
```

I have the browser Vivaldi installed which is chromium based, when I open it after a reboot, it asks me for password, and says the keyring wasn't unlocked when the system logged in. I think this started happening at the same time as the 5 minutes black screen issue. So they could be potentially related?

The black screen always stays there for the exact same duration every restart, 5 minutes.

I have this set to 5 minutes so I tried changing it to 1 minutes to see if it's related but it wasn't, the black screen still stayed for 5 minutes:

[image]

Comment: Something's timing out after 5 minutes. Use `sudo journalctl  --since="-12 minutes"` to inspect the logs.